# Need help understanding conditional statement syntax

Tags: apex, conditional

Can anyone describe, what the colon and question mark syntax between the two methods is for?

```
public PageReference initialize() {
        String profileId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('profileId');
        return profileId == null ? initializeView() : initializeUpdate();
 }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just another syntax for creating an IF() statement.  It is known as a ternary conditional operation.  Take a look [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex3_2.htm) for some more info on boolean and conditional statements.

**THIS**

```
return (profileId == null) ? initializeView() : initializeUpdate();
```

**Says the same thing as THIS**

```
if(profileId == null){
   return initializeView();
} else {
   return initializeUpdate();
}
```

Just helps save some code statements and makes the code a bit more readable.

Comment: Personaly, I like to put the condition into parenthesis for more readability like `return (profileId == null) ? initializeView() : initializeUpdate();`

Comment: Good point.  That might help segment the parts a bit better to help improve readability.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja sorry, I deleted my comment after you updated your question but before you replied to my comment